# Is Amumu's crying effected by Spell Vamp?

Tags: league-of-legends

While I was playing as Amumu, I began to wonder if his crying (W) was effected by Spell Vamp. Is it effected by it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure is. Because it's an AoE ability, Spell vamp is reduced to one-third effectiveness.

You can read all about Amumu [here](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Amumu), or Spell Vamp [here](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Spell_vamp)!